# Make Scrollbar for Single Div Use Full Page Scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage that displays its content in a single div. This div has its own scrollbar, but I want the scrollbar to cover the full page like any other website would. Is there a CSS or JavaScript solution to transfer a div's scrollbar to the `body`'s scrollbar?

Page in question: http://keavon.com/portfolio

Comment: Don't set a height on your content div, and make the footer have a fixed position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to make your footer have a fixed position.

You're going to have to change the way you transition between "pages", but you're a clever boy, so I'm sure you'll figure that out.

Here's a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/scJr1E?p=preview

The relevant bit being:

```
footer{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: With this solution, is it possible for me to keep my animation?

Comment: Yes, but you will probably have to do it differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the scrollbar with `overflow:hidden;` and enable scrollbar in your body with `overflow:auto`;

Comment: This wouldn't solve it in this case, because the bottom of the page is always the same. I just added a link to the page in question so you can see what I mean.

Comment: It's because your #bottom-navigation-frame is in absolute position.

Comment: How would I solve that? I removed `position:absolute;` but it did nothing. (version where it's removed isn't at that link)

Comment: It's not possible in this case because you have a unique page and if we remove the 'position absolute', the behavior will change in other view like Services for example. To have all like any other site, you must remove all position absolute, but you loose your animation..